# iOS EKRecurrenceRule exceptions and edits

Tags: ios, swift, icalendar

I need to sync a schedule created in an iOS app with the phone's calendar, and many are recurring events.

It's is easy enough to use `EKRecurrenceRule` for some of the functionality, but how does iOS Calendar handle moving or deleting a single event in a recurring series?

Answer (score 2):

When you create an event it is given an ID. You create recurrences (as you know) by using the `EKRecurrenceRule` objects, but the ID remains the same for all the events. You can then delete a single event like this:

```
func deleteEvent(eventIdentifier: String) -> Bool {
    var successful = false
    let eventToRemove = self.eventStore.eventWithIdentifier(eventIdentifier)
    if (eventToRemove != nil) {
        do {
            print("deleting single event")
            try self.eventStore.removeEvent(eventToRemove!, span: .ThisEvent)
            successful = true
        } catch {
            print("Bad things happened")
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print("no event with the identifier")
    }
    return successful
}
```

Or you can delete all of the events like this:

```
func deleteFutureEvents(eventIdentifier: String) -> Bool {
    var successful = false
    let eventToRemove = self.eventStore.eventWithIdentifier(eventIdentifier)
    if (eventToRemove != nil) {
        do {
            print("deleting future events")
            try self.eventStore.removeEvent(eventToRemove!, span: .FutureEvents)
            successful = true
        } catch {
            print("Bad things happened")
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print("no event with the identifier")
    }
    return successful
}
```

You can update single or all of the events in a similar manner using the event ID.